# JQ (GET ID based on NAME)

Tags: linux, json, jq, javascript

I get a long list of such arrays

```
{
    "id": "byu6g6c4cjys5mdkg5znh8ju8c",
    "create_at": 1511875272294,
    "update_at": 1511875272294,
    "delete_at": 0,
    "display_name": "BMA",
    "name": "BMA",
    "description": "",
    "email": "aleksandar.ivanov@random.com",
    "type": "O",
    "company_name": "",
    "allowed_domains": "",
    "invite_id": "gdgz1tbxuinntx1fbr1ax7kehy",
    "allow_open_invite": false,
    "scheme_id": null
  }
```

I want to get by JQ only the ID where the name is BMA.
At the moment I parse " jq -r '.[]["name"]" and I can filter the output from curl by name and I will get "BMA" and also 100 other names, but I need to filter only the ID where name is =BMA.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**jq**

You should be able to accomplish this with the following:

```
jq '.[] | select( .name == "BMA" ).id'
```

If name is `BMA` it will extract and output the corresponding `.id`.

To use the value of a shell variable, import it into `jq` with `--arg`:

```
myvariable=BMA
jq --arg name "$myvariable" '.[] | select( .name == $name ).id'
```

---

**[json](https://github.com/trentm/json)**

```
json -c 'this.name === "BMA"' -a id
```

Comment: Hello, I manage do it now , but I get this output though: jq: error: deposit/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select (.name==deposit-solutions) | .id
jq: error: solutions/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select (.name==deposit-solutions) | .id
jq: 2 compile errors    Any ideas?

Comment: @DenisHristov: Make sure you quote the names you are searching for as they are not defined variables.  Should be `select (.name=="deposit-solutions")` for example.

Comment: I cannot quote the names output as it is from another API call and when I  do "$test" it doesn't recognize the variable. Any help here?

Comment: You can try:  `jq ".[] | select (.name==\"$test\") | .id"`

Comment: This helped - man you are awesome. Last question is :     /usr/bin/curl -s -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx' -X GET -d 'per_page=500' 'https://blabla.random.com/api/v4/teams/$dam/members/$exist'  How to parse the variables. Cause at the moment it is not counting the variables

Comment: Shell variables won't expand inside single quotes (`'`) use double quotes instead (`"`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86402/discussion-between-denis-hristov-and-jesse-b).

Comment: Thanks so much I have no words to explain u how much u helped me

Answer (score 0):

alternative to jq solution is *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)*:

```
bash $ jtc -w'[name]:<BMA>+0 [-1] [id]' input.json
"byu6g6c4cjys5mdkg5znh8ju8c"
bash $
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`), first for extracting the relevant entries from the larger array (the ones having `name` equal to `BMA`), and then for extracting the `id` field from the selected entries:

```bash
mlr --j2n filter '$name == "BMA"' then cut -f id file
```

The `--j2n` option tells `mlr` invocation to read JSON and produce "indexed/tool-kit" output (essentially, just the data).

Given a file with a JSON array containing the object in the question text, this would output the single string `byu6g6c4cjys5mdkg5znh8ju8c` on a line.